# How to retrieve files from a folder from drive using python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I am new to the drive API and I am trying to access files from a folder named "users". So in order to navigate to the folder named "users" I am using the query

```
q="name = 'users' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
```

But the query is retrieving only the file that is named as "users". My motive is to loop through the contents of the folder named "users". How can I achieve that?

The flow of my directory Users is as given below

```
>Users 
     > 1 
        >1.json
     >2 
        >2.json
     >3
        > 3.json
```

I need to retrieve the json files

```
results = service.files().list(q="name = 'users' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",spaces = 'drive').execute()   
    items = results.get('files', [])
    print(type(items))

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Comment: first off remove the spaces  q="name='users' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"   Second if you are using that mime type its not returning a file its definitely returning the folder check the mime type on the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a good track using the query string parameter. Take a look at [the page of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms) explaining what are the options to query files.

In your case you want to search the files that are in a folder, taking a look at [search files page](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) from the documentation is clear that you want to include the clause `<file-id> in parents`.

```
q= "'1ObbqxfTThIsATestIdiieLBz' in parents"
```

After that you could iterate recursively through the files, you can check the mime type to see if the file is actually a folder.

---

**EDIT:** In case you want a function to print all the files you can look at this example:

```py
def files_in_folder(folder_id, service, deep=0):
    """Prints all the files inside folder_id recursively 

    Args:
       folder_id: The id of the current folder
       service: A google Drive service to execute requests
       deep: Keep track of how many sub-folder have we been 

    """
    files = service.files().list(q="'{}' in parents".format(folder_id)).execute()
    for _file in files["files"]:
        print("  "*deep + _file["name"])

        # Check if the file is a folder and print all the files inside
        if _file["mimeType"] == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder":
            files_in_folder(_file["id"], service, deep=deep+1)
```

In my case calling this function from the `root` folder I get:

```
Folder1
 Folder2
  Test
 Copy of Copy for posting
 File
Untitled form
```

Comment: How do I use mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder in an if statement?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a function that iterate recursively to get all the files and the "deepness" of said files.

Comment: Is it possible to open a file in read mode instead of downloading it and store the file contents in a variable?

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the responses that solve your problem so other people can benefit too.
Also I don't know what you mean but it seems like another whole question you could try to post. Look at [get_media](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.files.html#get_media), I think this is what you want.